# trouble making correct overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I need:

- Overlay to animate from bottom of page to an element id.
- be scrollable
- not show content behind it

Not sure why I can't figure this out. Here's what I have:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 0%;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    top: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #141414;
}
```

And then my js, which I just put `20%` as an arbitrary number, was going to try to calculate it based on where a particular element was.

```
  $("#overlay").animate({
    top: '20%',
    height: '100%'
  }, 1500);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v1nenq74/1/)'s a minimal example.

You might see a bunch of white space, which is irrelevant to the question, just the assets I have locally I didn't need to put in fiddle. If you go down to the blue boxes and press on either of the anchor tags, you'll see what is happening.

What's happening:

- the overlay does indeed take up most of the page, which is what I want. However, you can still scroll behind it.

> Why is this not what I want?

I just want to be able to trigger an overlay that will take up the page, not let you scroll behind it, and let you scroll the overlay.

I've tried 5-6 other overlay's I've found while googling, either they just automatically show (no animation) or they don't fit with the rest of my html.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your JS function you are targeting an ID and in your css your are targeting a class.
To target a element with class name in jQuery, use the `.` . To target an ID use the `#` sign.

```
 $("#overlay").animate({
    top: '20%',
    height: '100%'
 }, 1500);

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
```

Comment: Yes, I can see why you might think that's the issue, since I didn't include HTML (however I did include a fiddle which you would have seen that). However, they have both class and id of `overlay`. Obviously I shouldn't do that, but just trying to get a proof of concept going so names don't matter too much.